# How can I resolve this incompatible shape problem in my convolutionnal neural network on MNIST?

Tags: python, tensorflow, mnist

I built an image classification model on MNIST (CNN) and the model works very well on the test set. However, I have a dimension error when I upload an image from google, resize it, normalize it and feed it to my model. The input tensor shape for my model is `(None,28,28)` but it says that my input is `(None,28)` when I give a 28x28 pixel image to the model. How could I resolve this problem? [model_code.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvRIQ.png)

This is the error I have:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 28, 28) for input Tensor("flatten_input_2:0", shape=(None, 28, 28), dtype=float32), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 28). 

ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 784 but received input with shape [None, 28]
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The `None` in `(None,28,28)` is probably for batches. Add an additional dimension to your image before passing it to the network or use batches to predict at once

Answer (score 1):

you would need to reshape the image, using numpy it can easily be done with this

```
import numpy as np

image = np.array(image).reshape(1,28,28)
```

The error is probably due to tensorflow expecting many images, so if you provided 100 images the shape of the array would be (100,28,28) but since you have a single image it is in (28,28) as it should normally be. reshaping it to the correct format will solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

I guess you miss the `batch size` dimension, you just input an (28, 28) image, and the first 28 are recognized as `batch`, you need change your input to (1,28,28).

```py
tf.reshape(image, (1,28,28))
```